# Eclipse : Can we make modifications on to the source code while debugging the Application inside Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, remote-debugging

Can we make modifications on to the source code while  debugging the 
Application inside Eclipse

Hi ,

Assume that i have this piece of code under Eclipse IDe

```
          public void kk()
        {
        try
        {
        int jj = 20;

        if(jj==20)
            throw new Exception();

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Assume that the code has entered inside the catch block due to the condition jj==20 , can we modify the code and bring the debug control back ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - control will return to the top of the method after you make your changes & save.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, its possible. But within specified limit.

As an example, it is possible to change code inside a method, but not inside a class.